# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, resource-files

I inherited a big SharePoint application, that I am trying to setup on a system(I had to reinstall SP 2016 for some reason).

I have a WebPart which is using resource files for different languages.

When I open the page after adding the WebPart, I am getting an error on this line:

```
string InitialValue = GetGlobalResourceObject(resourceFile, "InitialValue_Choose").ToString();
```

Error:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"Resources.enUS.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"App_GlobalResources.ilmurq6l\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
```

When I have not changed anything in the project, what could be causing this error?